# json_decode access nested array with multiple identical keys

Tags: arrays, json

I am trying to access a specific value from an array, but have difficulties fetching it. More specifically it is the value DealerCarExtended-->ImageIds-->ImageId-->Id, but my problem is that ImageIds is an array with multiple ImageId's. I use son_decode, but the code below obviously doesn't work.

```
$response = file_get_contents( 'http://api.autoit.dk/car/GetCarsExtended/391B093F-BB4A-45AA-BEFF-7B33842401EA' );

$myArray = json_decode($response,true);

$myArray = $myArray[0];

echo $myArray['ImageIds']['ImageId']['Id'];
```

I'm sure that this is trivial for most of you guys but i'm a newbie in this :-)

Answer (score 0):

A working example :

```
$response = file_get_contents( 'http://api.autoit.dk/car/GetCarsExtended/391B093F-BB4A-45AA-BEFF-7B33842401EA' );

$myArray = json_decode($response,true);

$myArray = $myArray[0];

# fetching second array item :
echo $myArray['ImageIds'][1]['Id']
```